# Line chart with two value variables showing one as total sum and the other as actual values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to create a line chart with two separate lines, by applying separate filters. To do so I have used slicers to create two tables CF1 and CF2 which is the original data filtered for the respective filters on the LHS and RHS of the data below (using relationships).

However, when displaying the information on a chart the second set of data is showing as the sum of the values instead of values as CF1 is.

[image]

I have tried creating a line chart with only CF1 or CF2 as the values and that works without issue.

Comment: In addition to what  @Marcus said. Add a calendar table with  a CALENDARAUTO() function and link dates with both tables. Then use Calenadar.[Date] as X-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this happen you need a common X-axis column to establish the evaluation context.

Now you are using the date column from one of the tables, say `Table 1` which causes the measure that scans your `Table 2` to just sum all entries, since the evaluation context does not filter `Table 2` at all.

Read up on calendar tables and implement that. There are plenty of resources on this on the Web. See [this example](https://radacad.com/creating-calendar-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-functions) from Radacad, for instance.